# Compare objects in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to do a "deep" comparison of two object in Angular? What I would like to do is compare each key/value pair. For example:

Object 1

```
{
   key1: "value1",
   key2: "value2",
   key3: "value3"
}
```

Object 2

```
{
   key1: "value1",
   key2: "newvalue",
   key3: "value3" 
}
```

What I need is for the comparison to fail since only one of the key/value pairs is diffent. In other words ALL of the key/value pairs must match exactly or else failure. Is this something already built into Angular. I'm sure I could write my own service if I really needed to, but I was hoping it was already built in. Similar to angular.equals.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

To compare two objects you can use:

`angular.equals(obj1, obj2)`

It does a deep comparison and does not depend on the order of the keys
See [AngularJS DOCS](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/angular.equals) and a little [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dv3xseVGK0B3rDRksnUM?p=preview)

```
var obj1 = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  key3: {a: "aa", b: "bb"}
}

var obj2 = {
  key2: "value2",
  key1: "value1",
  key3: {a: "aa", b: "bb"}
}

angular.equals(obj1, obj2) //<--- would return true
```

Comment: Note that angular.equals tests [identity, **not** equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447024/javascript-comparison-operators-identity-vs-equality).  
TL;DR: `angular.equals( { id: "12" }, { id: 12 } ) // is false`

Comment: @bobjones angular.equals returns true based on identity OR deep equality, so your proposed example would return true. see the [angular.equals documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) , specifically
    Two objects or values are considered equivalent if at least one of the following is true

Comment: @tommyTheHitMan: bobjones example returns `false` because, based on identity, `"12"===12 // is false`. Just try it out.

Comment: And if you need a diff object for tracking history for rollbacks, see this...
https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6193808

Comment: what if i need to find the difference between theese two, angular.equals only returns true or false, I need to have the difference if the answer is false.

Comment: @PreenaKhanuja this is more a new question rather than a comment. I would suggest you ask a new question, you will also get more help. Look at this first it may answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264430/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-differences-between-two-javascript-object-graphs

Comment: A quick note:  angular.equals() ignores all properties beginning with $, and all properties whose values are functions, when both arguments are objects.

Comment: I came here searching for object copying for keeping track of state. So on a related note, there is also `angular.copy()` for obtaining decoupled `obj1` and `obj2`.

Answer (score 27):

Assuming that the order is the same in both objects, just `stringify` them both and compare!

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) == JSON.stringify(obj2);
```

Comment: angular.equals(obj1,obj2) should also work. It does not depend from the keys order and it is deep (it is called recursively) http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/angular.equals

Comment: That would be a very bad assumption!

Comment: `angular.toJson` would also remove the $$hashKeys

Comment: This does not work if the order of properties is different. So

JSON.stringify({a:1, b:1}) === JSON.stringify({b:1, a:1})

is false.

Comment: @PeterB feels like I mentioned that somewhere in the answer...

Answer (score 5):

Bit late on this thread. 
angular.equals does deep check, however does anyone know that why its behave differently if one of the member contain "$" in prefix ?

You can try this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dv3xseVGK0B3rDRksnUM?p=preview)  with following input

```
var obj3 = {}
obj3.a=  "b";
obj3.b={};
obj3.b.$c =true;

var obj4 = {}
obj4.a=  "b";
obj4.b={};
obj4.b.$c =true;

angular.equals(obj3,obj4);
```

Comment: From the Angular documentation: "During a property comparison, properties of function type and properties with names that begin with $ are ignored." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

Answer (score 2):

I know it's kinda late answer but I just lost about half an hour debugging cause of this, It might save someone some time.

BE MINDFUL, If you use `angular.equals()` on objects that have property `obj.$something` **(property name starts with $)** those properties will get ignored in comparison.

Example:

```
var obj1 = {
  $key0: "A",
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  key3: {a: "aa", b: "bb"}
}

var obj2 = {
  $key0: "B"
  key2: "value2",
  key1: "value1",
  key3: {a: "aa", b: "bb"}
}

angular.equals(obj1, obj2) //<--- would return TRUE (despite it's not true)
```