# Identify object in angular js has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onchange

I have a backend object that i receive from the server and sent to server.
I give a permission to my users to change the backend object.
I would like to identify if the backend object has changed from the save point.

How can i identify it?

For example:
I have a module called

```
app.controller('PanelCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.action = "";
$scope.selectedItem = "";
    $scope.compoundItem = [];

...
```

I have in the compound item array of Objects.
I would like to know if something is changed whether the change occures in the primitives and whether in the compoundItem...

Comment: I think you are looking for [scope.$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 9):

Edit: two scenarios 1) client check (the original post) 2) server check (extended based on the comments)

#### 1) check on the Client

*do not worry about performance of the below steps. And if you do, please read more about performance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/)*

The answer is: [`angular.equals()`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/angular.equals) and a similar scenario is described here:  [Developer Guide / forms](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) *(it is about validation)*. In the section **Binding to form and control state**, we can see the script *(an extract)*:

```
function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.master = {};

  $scope.update = function(user) {
    $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
  };

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
  };

  $scope.isUnchanged = function(user) {
    return angular.equals(user, $scope.master);
  };
}
```

What we can see here, is what we need. Firstly copy the source state *(inside the update function)*. We can change `isUchnaged` any time, while using the [`angular.equals()`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/angular.equals)

Also check [Compare objects in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20410833/1679310)

NOTE: A comment to the angular.copy(). I found, that in some cases, better is to use the lo-dash [.deepClone()](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)

#### 2) Server side solution

In case that *(as Dalorzo expects)* are interesting in the comparison of the server, persisted version and the client. It could make sense, if we want to check if some one **else** has already changed the "Entity". In some other *transaction*

There are in general many techniques, but the most effective is versioning. On the persistence layer, we have to introduce some value, which is changed/incremented every time the "Update" is executed. In case of MS SQL Server it would be the **`rowversion`**, see [more here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

Then, during any sucesfull UPDATE operation, this version will be changed, and we know that data on the client are stale... there are newer on the server.

**Summary with version**:

Our check could be very easy:

- Compare the Client (current) **Version** property and
- ask the server for the latest persisted.

This is a standard way I am using with NHiberante ([read more here](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency))

Comment: Despite of the **Dalorzo** down-vote, I would suggest, check these links. they are comming from Guide to AngularJS Documentation...

Comment: Why this is down voted ? What is the wrong ? to compare two object definitely we can use `angular.equals`.

Comment: @Radim Köhler Tthe down-vote is because you missed " I would like to identify if the backend object has changed from the save point". I couldn't understand how this will be met from your code above. My apologies I thought you will notice it.

Comment: @Dalorzo, I've updated my answer, extending it to solve your expectation that the issue is between client and server. Does this answer seem to be correct?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to my mine is to use 
`$timeout(isDifferent,xtime)`

where:

`isDifferent`= is your custom function to get the backend object or identify when it has changed.

`xtime`= is and integer value in milliseconds which represents how often your function will execute.

Comment: But as you described i need to compare between the current backend object and the saved one. But it is huge with many fields and objects. Can it be something more simple? I need to identify if there is only a change... in order to figure out if i have to send update request to the server or not.

Comment: IsDifferent function can do anything it is up to use the code that you think more efficient.