# Angular equals with deep comparison and return difference on each item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to compare two arrays using `angular.equals` and get list of items that are different from each other.

For example:

```
var obj1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'john', age: 30, height: 6 },
    { id: 2, name: 'ben' , age: 20, height: 5 }
];
var obj2 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'martin', age: 25, height: 6 },
    { id: 2, name: 'ben'   , age: 20, height: 5 }
];
```

Now doing `angular.equals(obj1, obj2)` will return `false`.

Here I want to compare each item from different arrays and alert differences or show different color when I display in UI.

Assuming `obj1` is from HTML form and `obj2` is from service.

Result expected:

**.id[1] name changed to john,age changed to 25**
or
**.get false or true when I compare each item in**.

Comment: There is no "out of the box" way of doing this in Angular. Ultimately, you just need to iterate through each array value and compare. Underscore/lodash may or may not help you beyond the Array.prototype methods available in JS.

Comment: Can you please share in JSFiddle if you have solution , I am struggling in comparing and getting exact difference for each item.

Comment: I don't have a solution because I haven't worked through the problem. It would be best for you to post a Fiddle of what you have and update your question with more specifics about what you've tried.

Comment: Marc Kline, I have updated the solution I tried here http://jsfiddle.net/Ebv3p/60/

Comment: I updated it with just the very beginning of the diff you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/Ebv3p/62/ I used Underscore, which I imagine you'll want to continue using. I suggest becoming acquainted with the methods it offers as you consider the problem you're looking to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't have a built-in function for this. You should use the library [deep-diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff) for this.

```js
var first = [
    { id: 1, name: 'john', age: 30, height: 6 },
    { id: 2, name: 'ben' , age: 20, height: 5 }
];

var second = [
    { id: 1, name: 'martin', age: 25, height: 6 },
    { id: 2, name: 'ben'   , age: 20, height: 5 }
];

var result = diff(first, second);

// result => [
//    { kind: 'E', path: [0, 'name'], lhs: 'john', rhs: 'martin' },
//    { kind: 'E', path: [0, 'age' ], lhs: 30    , rhs: 25       }
// ]
```

Answer (score -2):

As klode stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409712/compare-objects-in-angular), there is an option to deep compare **using angular only** without additional dependencies:

```
angular.equals(obj1, obj2)
```

Comment: The does not address the OP's request for a diff that indicates _which_ items have changed.