# Compare Two JSON Objects to See Changes Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I need to refactor my program to take a JSON obj, store it somewhere, make a bunch of changes, then compare the two objects to see what has been changed, deleted, and added.

I'm not sure of a way to do this in JS, so could anyone advise a way to do this in Angular (the object comparison part)?  Otherwise, I'm going to have to make a ton of changes to the way my program runs / try it from the backend.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409712/compare-objects-in-angular

Comment: I don't need equality.  I need the difference between the objects

Comment: Short of iterating over each object there's no easy way to accomplish this. You can iterate over each property in each subobject (think recursive call) such as what's in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: That's sort of what I feared.  Unfortunately, that would be a real mess with the json structure that I have.

Comment: library `js-data` might help you. It tracks changes

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only built in operation for object comparison is the `==`/`===` equality operators, which use reference equality: A is B, rather than A is equal to B.

What you want is a list of change descriptors describing the difference between two objects.

As identified in the comments, this is going to need a recursive traversal of the objects, using a mixture of reference and existence checks.

The following algorithm is a quick implementation of an idea. The objects are traversed and their changes are described with a list of objects. Just like the objects themselves, the changes are nested, but have a unique id, based on their location within the object (so it could be flattened).

```
function diff(a, b, namespace) {
  namespace = (namespace || '') + '.';

  var keysInA = Object.keys(a),
      keysInB = Object.keys(b);

  var diffA = keysInA.reduce(function(changes, key) {
    var ns = namespace + key;

    if(typeof b[key] == 'undefined') {
      return changes.concat([{ type: 'DELETED', id: ns }]);
    }

    if(a[key] !== b[key]) {
      return changes.concat([{ type: 'CHANGED', id: ns }]);
    }

    if(typeof a[key] == b[key] == 'object') {
      return diff(a[key], b[key], ns);
    }

    return changes; 
  }, []);

  var diffB = keysInB.reduce(function(changes, key) {
    var ns = namespace + key;

    if(typeof a[key] == 'undefined') {
      return changes.concat([{ type: 'ADDED', id: ns }]);
    }

    return changes;
  }, []);

  return diffA.concat(diffB);
}
```

For example we take the original state of an object.

```
var a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

And the new state.

```
var b = { a: 2, c: 3, d: 5 };
```

Then run them with the `diff` function.

```
diff(a, b);
```

It returns a list of the changes.

```
[
  { id: '.a', type: 'CHANGED' },
  { id: '.b', type: 'DELETED' },
  { id: '.d', type: 'ADDED' }
]
```

Obviously, you would have to adapt this algorithm to make it fit your criteria for what constitutes a change. You might want to look at [deep equality](http://dailyjs.com/2012/12/03/js101-deep-equal/), rather than comparing references the whole way down.

Comment: doing a lot of work that `angular.equals()` already has built in

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  This definitely helps me see how this could be implemented.

Comment: This is  not working for object array and nested object, do you have solution for that as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my implementation of Dan's suggestion here in case it will help someone who wants to see an actual implementation:

```
var propertiesToIgnore = ['.indexesTracked', '.notInSyncWithDb', '.date', '.details.updatedAt', '.autoLoadLocalStorage', '.deletionQueue']; //these are extraneous properties added to project that should not be represented in interface (and not tracked)
var keysToIgnore = ['addAllDatacuts', 'datacutNames']; // this just looks at the property rather than the above which matches from the project root

function diff(a, b, namespace, firstCall) {
    namespace = firstCall ? (namespace || '') : (namespace || '') + '.';

    var keysInA = Object.keys(a),
        keysInB = Object.keys(b);

    var diffA = keysInA.reduce(function(changes, key) {
      var ns = namespace + key;

      if (propertiesToIgnore.indexOf(ns) !== -1 || keysToIgnore.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        return changes;
      }

      if (key == '$$hashKey') {
        return changes;
      }

      if (angular.equals(a[key], b[key])) { // whole chain is equal so I do not need to iterate over this branch
        return changes;
      }

      if (typeof b[key] == 'undefined') {
        return changes.concat([{ type: 'DELETED', id: ns }]);
      }

      if (a[key] !== b[key] && (typeof b[key] !== 'object' || typeof a[key] !== 'object')) {
        return changes.concat([{ type: 'UPDATED', id: ns }]);
      }

      if (typeof b[key] === 'object' && typeof a[key] === 'object') {
        return changes.concat(diff(a[key], b[key], ns));
      }
      if (a[key] === null || b[key] === null) { // avoids values that are null as js considers null an object
        return changes;
      }

      if(typeof a[key] == 'object' && typeof b[key] == 'object' && typeof a[key].getMonth !== 'function' && typeof b[key].getMonth !== 'function') { // last part necessary to make sure it is not a date object
        return diff(a[key], b[key], ns);
      }

      return changes;
    }, []);

    var diffB = keysInB.reduce(function(changes, key) {
      var ns = namespace + key;

      if (propertiesToIgnore.indexOf(ns) !== -1 || keysToIgnore.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        return changes;
      }

      if (key == '$$hashKey') {
        return changes;
      }

      if (typeof a[key] == 'undefined') {
        return changes.concat([{ type: 'ADDED', id: ns }]);
      }

      return changes;
    }, []);

    return diffA.concat(diffB);
  }

  $scope.changes = diff(dbData, $scope.project, '');
```