# Detection of Index in Angular: indexOf() does not work properly because of $$hasKeys?

Tags: angularjs, hash, key, indexof

Following Situation:

```
role: { roleid=3,  name="admin"}

availableRoles:
    [
        { roleid=3,  name="admin",  $$hashKey="object:222"}, 
        { roleid=4,  name="plain user",  $$hashKey="object:223"}
    ]

currentRoles: 
    [
        { roleid=3,  name="admin"}
    ]
```

Following Trys:

```
currentRoles.indexOf(role);  // works properly and outputs 0
availableRoles.indexOf(role);  // does not work
```

I can imagine, this occurs because of $$hasKeys. But I didn't put them there, AngularJS does augment these data.

How can I overcome this situation?

Is there a function like: ignore Angular HasKeys in this Datastructure?

Comment: You can itearate with help of angular foreach. Directly you can't check it beacuse indexof works direct array not an aray contain objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Angular object comparison:
[Compare objects in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409712/compare-objects-in-angular)

So you can just write the function:

```
function arrayObjectIndexOf(arr, obj){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(angular.equals(arr[i], obj)){
            return i;
        }
    };
    return -1;
}
```

**--ORIGINAL--**

JavaScript saves objects as pointers, therefore, two objects even if has the same data in them, have different values (the value of the pointer in the memory).

Code example:

```
var role = { roleid:3,  name:"admin"};

var availableRoles =
    [
        { roleid:3,  name:"admin"}, 
        { roleid:4,  name:"plain user",  $$hashKey:"object:223"}
    ];
alert(availableRoles.indexOf(role));
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjobaW

So it does not relate to the hashKey. To compare to objects (and such, find the index in an array) you must create a loop of comparison, or overload the "==" operator of Object to compare values and not pointers, which I dont believe you are allowed to do in JS.

Comment: We are here within Angular, there should be maybe an Angular Solution?

Answer (score 0):

- Best way is not to have such objects...
- You can use angular filter:

> ```
> function contains(arr, id) {
>     return $filter('filter')(arr, {roleid : id}, true).length != 0;
> }
> ```

- You can use some other js library (lodash, underscore, ...) for such things.