# Javascript, if input type range condition

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what's wrong with my script. When the input reaches 1, it should display the alert but it does't. But if i replace (value === 1) with (value === value), it displays the alert every time i change the input. So i know the problem is with the syntax "(value === 1)". I tried everything. 5 hours weren't enough for me to find a solution on the internet, so i hope someone tells me if i made mistake with the syntax or something. Thank you for your time.

```html
<input id="carrotate123" type="range" min="0" max="3" value="2" oninput="getInput(this.value)">

<script>
function getInput(value) {
    var rangeInput = document.getElementById("carrotate123").value;
    var value = rangeInput.value;
    if (value === 1) { 
        alert("First"); 
    }
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `===`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5447024/1531971 (What type is `value`? Is it something that makes sense to compare in this manner with `1`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things wrong here.  First, you have an extra call to `value`.  The cleanest solution to that is to remove the one on the `rangeInput` assignment.  But you could also simply use that value and skip defining `rangeInput` altogether.

The second one is covered in the answer from Szab.  You need to change how you compare your target value with the String supplied by the `input` element.  Combining these looks like this:

```html
<input id="carrotate123" type="range" min="0" max="3" value="2" oninput="getInput(this.value)">

<script>
function getInput(value) {
    var rangeInput = document.getElementById("carrotate123");
    var value = rangeInput.value;
    // or replace the previous two lines with
    // var value = document.getElementById("carrotate123").value
    if (value == 1) { // or: if (value === '1')
        alert("First"); 
    }
  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `===` operator means strict equality - both in value and in type. In your case, `value` is a `string` (`value` property of DOM elements usually returns a `string`) while `1` is obviously a `number`. Consider the examples below:

```
1 == 1 // true
1 == "1" // true
1 === 1 // true
1 === "1" // false
```

You should consider changing `===` to `==` (which performs automatic type coercion) or compare your value with `"1"` (as a string).

More about differences between comparison operators: [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison)