# Why do I get different results with "=" vs. "===" in javascript with Conditional (Ternary) Operators?

Tags: javascript, boolean, ternary-operator

I want to make a program in javascript that yields "true" when two integers are equal and "false" when they are not.

I've tried using the "=" signs and the "===" sign, but I don't know why the results of program change depending on which sign I use, even without changing the numbers in the functions.

This code results in "false", which is what I want:

```
function checkEqual(a, b) {
  return (a === b ? true : false );
}

checkEqual(1, 2);
```

This code results in "true", which is NOT what I want:

```
function checkEqual(a, b) {
  return (a = b ? true : false );
}

checkEqual(1, 2);
```

The numbers in checkEqual() are the same in both attempts, but I want to know why the second one is "true".

Comment: 1 `=` sign means you are assigning a value from right variable to left variable. You should be asking `==` vs `===`

Comment: single equal to `=` is setting the right variable as to left, this should be `Uncaught Syntax error`

Comment: I would like to add the I got the solution with only one equals sign from free code camp [here](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/certifications/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/use-the-conditional-ternary-operator/) which I thought was a legitimate source, so please excuse my faux pas.

Comment: You missed the `warning` text that is in big font.

Comment: FreeCodeCamp is a good source, but that happens to be a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning `a` value with `b` value. Thus, `a` becomes true.

What you're trying to do is to check with equality operator `==`.

- `=` is assignment operator.
- `==` is equality operator.
- `===` is strict equality operator.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) to deep dive.

Answer (score 4):

`=` does not check equality, it is only used for assignment. The operators that check for equality in JavaScript are `==` (for "abstract" equality) and `===` (for "strict" equality). If `a` and `b` are both numbers, `==` and `===` will work the same.

Comment: And `!=` and `!==`.

Answer (score 2):

### First case (`===`):

```
function checkEqual(a, b) {
  return (a === b ? true : false );
}

checkEqual(1, 2);
```

Here you are using the identity operator (a.k.a. strict equality operator). It checks if the values are equal (and of the same type).

Since `a` is `1` and `b` is `2`, then `a === b` becomes `false` (since they are different). And of course `false ? true : false` is `false`. So, the whole thing returns `false`. Yes, you might just do this:

```
function checkEqual(a, b) {
  return a === b;
}

checkEqual(1, 2);
```

---

### Second case (`=`):

```
function checkEqual(a, b) {
  return (a = b ? true : false );
}

checkEqual(1, 2);
```

Here you are using the assigment operator. This is not an equality or identity check.

In this case, `a = b` assigns the value of `b` to `a` and returns it. So both `a` and `b` will be `2`, and `a = b` evaluates to `2`. Finally, since `2` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, `2 ? true : false` is `true`.

Note: that also means that if you were to pass a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value for `b`, you would get `false`. For example with the call: `checkEqual(1, null);` The value passed to `a` is irrelevant.

---

### The case you didn't do (`==`):

```
function checkEqual(a, b) {
  return (a == b ? true : false );
}

checkEqual(1, 2);
```

Here you would be using the equality operator. It checks if the values are equal (however, it is free to convert the values to check).

Similarly to the first one, this will return `false`. What is the difference? Well, types. In Javascript `"1" == 1` is `true` but `"1" === 1` is `false`. That is, by using `==` you are allowing the runtime to convert the values in order to compare them, but with `===` you are not.

See [JavaScript comparison operators: Identity vs. Equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5447024/402022) and [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/402022)

Answer (score 0):

In your second code snippet, you are using the *assignment operator `=`* rather than one of the *comparison operators (`==` or `===`)*, which is the main error here.

Now, to concisely answer your *specific* question, [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) reports that: `"The assignment operation evaluates to the assigned value."`

So, for example:

```
a = b ? true : false  --> if b != 0, this returns true,
                      --> if b = 0, this returns false
```

Comment: What? I couldn't understand.

Comment: The OP asked why their second case evaluates to `true`. The assignment operation returns a value itself (like in C). And the returned value is the one assigned, in this case the value of `b`.

Comment: Your code still uses the `=` (assignment) operator.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes. I am answering the `why it evaluates to true` question. Let me add that OP should use a comparison operator.